# Smoothing/Aggregating polygon in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, watershed

I have this one big polygon separated by a big gap/space like this

[image]

Can anyone advise how can i edit, so that the space should be narrow, smooth without a big gap like this?

[image]

What function should i use? cartography tools? Spatial Analyst function? Watershed?

Comment: What has "Watershed" got to do with your question?

Comment: Your examples are very confusing. I see scores of polygons, not a big one with gaps. Please use words to describe the context of your pictures, and alter the pictures to be clearly  described by th words.

Answer (score 1):

You can try tool [Integrate](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/integrate.htm):

> Integrate is used to maintain the integrity of shared feature
>   boundaries by making features coincident if they fall within the
>   specified x,y tolerance. Features that fall within the specified x,y
>   tolerance are considered identical or coincident.

[image]

Before running the tool backup your data:

> Caution: This tool modifies the input data. See Tools with no outputs
>   for more information and strategies to avoid undesired data changes.

If the polygons are in fact one (=one multipart polygon) you might want to run [Multipart To Singlepart](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/multipart-to-singlepart.htm) prior to Integrate.